# Update the base class property while deep cloning

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, deep-copy, system.reflection

I have a following base class

```
public class BaseEntity
{
   public Guid Id{get; set;}
   public string Name{get; set;}
}
```

I have number of child class which inherit from this Base class. For example:

```
public Class Employee : BaseEntity
{
   public string UserId {get; set;} 
   public Role EmpRole {get; set;}
   public IList<Department> EmpDepartment {get; set;}
}

public class Role : BaseEntity
{
   public string Description{get; set;}
}

public Class Department : BaseEntity
{
   Public int NumOfEmployees {get; set;}
}
```

Now I need to create a deep copy of employee object and have to update Id field for all the properties which are inherited from BaseEntity Class.

I am using following code to implement it but its not working:

```
public static T DeepClone<T>(T obj)
{
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
    using (stream)
    {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
        stream.seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var newObj = (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        return updateClone(newObj);
    }
}

public static T UpdateClone<T>(T obj)
{
     var newObj = obj;
     foreach (PropertyInfo p in obj.GetType().BaseType.GetProperties())
     {
         if(p.Name.ToString().ToLower() = "id")
         {
             p.SetValue(newObj,Guid.NewGuid());
         }
     }

    return newObj;
}
```

This will update the Id Employee.

But I need to update Ids of all the properties inside Employee as well.

Can anyone help me with this?

Edited: I have already tried technique of looping through all the properties and updating Id but the object I using is very large and with this approach performance of code gets a lot of hit. In some cases it takes somewhere around a couple of minutes to complete the process. I am looking for a better approach to fix this problem.

Comment: Alternatively you could use the copy constructor pattern, which will work with inheritance, however if you have a lot of classes it gets tedious because you have to remember to implement the copy constructor for all of those classes. Just a thought.

Comment: yes, I have lots of classes, and all the classes have lots of fields in it. I have looped through all the properties and update the id but I with that I am getting a lot of hit on performance.

Comment: Well, with `UpdateClone<T>` you still loop through all properties, so that is still not better. If you need to update a lot of the properties in each type you will end up with boatloads of special cases in `UpdateClone<T>`, That doesn't look very good either. At this point I would decentralize it. There is a balance that you have to strike, lots of place the same code -> centralize/abstract. One place, lots of special cases -> decentralize.

Comment: Thanks Frank. I have to update a single property "Id" in lots of classes. Depth in a class can go to nth level. I am thinking of creating separate Updater class to update the properties once the object is cloned but that will not keep my code generic. Please let me know if there is a better approach to it.

Comment: Is it only the `id` or are there other values that need to be updated? If it is only the `id` you could put an interface onto the relevant classes, and make a generic constraint. If this should be the case I can show you that relatively easy.

Comment: yes, its only Id that I need to update. And its in BaseEntity class. but in some classes BaseEntity is inherited directly but in some cases it is not directly inherited but available in hierarchy. It will be great if you can show be how to put an interface and use it to update the Id.

Answer (score 0):

Well you're looping just through the property of the base that for that object, you should loop through all of the properties present on the object, and then update them

Something like this:

```
public static T UpdateClone<T>(T obj)
{
    var newObj = obj;
    foreach (PropertyInfo p in obj.GetType().BaseType.GetProperties())
    {
        if (p.Name.ToString().ToLower() == "id")
        {
            p.SetValue(newObj, Guid.NewGuid());
        }
    }

    foreach (PropertyInfo pInfo in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var propertyObject = pInfo.GetValue(obj);
        if (propertyObject != null)
        {
            if (propertyObject is IEnumerable && !(propertyObject is string))
            {
                foreach (object p in (propertyObject as IEnumerable))
                {
                    UpdateClone(p);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (PropertyInfo p in propertyObject.GetType().BaseType.GetProperties())
                {
                    if (p.Name.ToString().ToLower() == "id")
                    {
                        p.SetValue(propertyObject, Guid.NewGuid());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  return newObj;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried this approach. Performance is getting a lot of hit with this approach. Objects which I am using are very large sometime clone process itself takes around a couple of minutes to complete. I am looking for better approach.

Comment: if that is the case i recommend looking into the prototype design pattern, maybe this will help https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/prototype